# Add a CustomAction button to a Custom Content List

Tags: custom-list, custom-actions

I want to add a new CustomAction button on my custom list in Sharepoint 2010, programmatically.
(Bear in mind that I am still a bit new to SharePoint)

I've followed the instructions given on these pages, but still can't figure out how to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500259(v=office.14).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768562(v=office.12).aspx

To start with I just wanted to add the "Bing it!" button from the first example to my already existing custom content list.
But when I add a new CustomAction element in my project as described in the example, the button only appears
on standard custom lists, and not on my custom content list.

What I gathered from the second example is that it wanted me to set the ID of my custom content type to the
same as the content type I inherit from. So I tried setting it and the RegistrationId on my
CustomAction to 0x01.
But this only messed up the layout of my add/edit forms and still did not show the button.

From before I had the ID of the list as 0x01008d248abf95d04c7a86ef829bc968282a, so I tried setting the
RegistrationId of the CustomAction to this, but again the button did not appear anywhere.

Adding the CustomAction with SharePoint Designer works fine, but I need to do it programmatically.

I dont really know where to go from here.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I was setting the ID of the list to an ID with lower-case letters, as it seems unsupported.

Changing the ID (0x01008d248abf95d04c7a86ef829bc968282a) to upper-case (0x01008D248ABF95D04C7A86EF829BC968282A) and then setting the RegistrationId of the CustomAction to this ID worked like a charm.